# View two SQL tables simultaneously without using union

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I am using PostgreSQL and I am trying to view two tables at the same time. Yes, I already know about union, but my objective is to view two tables simultaneously without using union. The top picture is what I am trying to achieve and the bottom picture is my error. Thanks in advance.

[image: What I am trying to achieve.]
[image: What I have so far.]

Comment: Pasting screenshots here should be avoited. But in MSSQL console you are executing two separate queries. It seem to allow that kind  (rather bad in my opinion) of syntax.

Comment: That is a feature of the SQL client, not the database. What happens if you properly terminate each statement with `;` and run both as a "script" (if that is possible in DBeaver?)

Comment: See https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=682

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I am able to execute the two tables without errors when I properly terminate each statement with a semicolon. However, the tables are in separate tabs. Thanks for the help though.